# break out of for loop when it iterates over 4th even number

Tags: java, loops, iteration, break

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {


            if (i%2==0) {
                System.out.println("My Name is Nikki\r\n" + `enter code here`I am learning Core Java");
            }
            break;
//          else {
//              System.out.println("My name is U\r\n" + `enter code here`
// I am learning core java");
//          }

        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Solution (counter variable):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i%2==0) {
            System.out.println("My Name is Nikki\r\n" + `enter code here`I am learning Core Java");
            counter++;
        }
        if (counter == 4){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can just loop from 0 to 8 incrementing by 2. Here's the code to do that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i += 2) {
        if (i%2==0) {
            System.out.println("My Name is Nikki\r\n" + `enter code here`I am learning Core Java");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done very simple with counter:

```
public static void printFirstEvenNumber(int total) {
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < total; i += 2, j++)
        System.out.println("Even number " + i + ", count is " + j);
}
```

---

**Demo**

```
printFirstEvenNumber(4);

Even number 0, count is 0
Even number 2, count is 1
Even number 4, count is 2
Even number 6, count is 3
```

Answer (score -2):

this is a solution

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        if (i%2==0) {
            System.out.println("My Name is Nikki\r\nI am learning Core Java");
            count++;
        }
        if (count == 4) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So why are we using count++ here? Is variable i a part of variable count? Can you explain the logic behind this creation of count variable?

Comment: it count the times of even number has be iterated